# How to prevent users from changing values/rows in a database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, encryption, hash

I have a database table that I'd like to prevent a user from modifying the values/rows.  How can I accomplish this?

Here are some criteria:

1. The table to be protected has a single column with data stored in plain text.
2. Other columns can be added to the table if needed to help protect the single column.
3. My application needs to have the ability to add, edit, and delete the values/rows in the table.
4. For this question, I am assuming the user has full and direct admin/read/write access to the database, i.e. the user can log into the database the execute queries directly.
5. If the user changes the values directly in the database, my application needs to flag that this has happened when it inspects the table.
6. There are other tables in the database, but they do not need to be protected in this manner.  They can be used, if needed, to help protect the first table.
7. A database engine agnostic solution would be nice, but I am using SQL Server 2005 or later.

For example:

Let's say my table has 3 rows with data "A", "B", "C".  My application should be able change the values to "A", "B", "D", but not my user (through direct modification of the database).  Additionally, I expect that if my application changes the values to "A", "B", "D", the user cannot edit the table directly to go back to "A", "B", "C".  If that happens, the application will flag that the table has been tampered with.

Comment: This can all be controlled within the application, so unless you give your users direct database access you should have no problems. If your user has direct database access, you can tweak the privileges that user has. Some RDBMS support privileges at the column level as well as auditing, so if any changes are made, you will know. Without knowing which RDBMS you're using, that part of the question is harder to answer.

Comment: A database engine agnostic solution would be nice, but I am using SQL Server 2005 or later.  I am assuming the user has direct database access with access to modify anything in the database.

Comment: Do you care if the users modify the database indirectly, e.g. by writing their own application or using Access, Excel, ... ? You only want to prevent changes made using SSMS?

Comment: @sparks This isn't something RDBMS typically handle, so a database agnostic solution will be hard to come by. But if the user has the rights to modify *anything* in the database (eg: sysadmin level access) then you are probably short of luck because obviously they can bypass any restriction you put on them and/or erase any audit trail (unless it's external). Is there any reason why you can't give these users DB accounts with limited privileges?

Comment: @HABO Yes, if the user writes their own application, uses Access, Excel, or SSMS to modify the table, I'd like to be able to catch that with my application.

Comment: Do you care who the user is when they use your application, i.e. could the application use a unique database account rather than the user's default access? If so, you could do something like add a trigger that checks the connection information and uses `RaIsError` to discourage the unworthy.

Comment: @NullUserException The application and database will be running from the user's servers.  This is a question we've been tossing around at the office for awhile and haven't come up with a solution for.  Just hoping someone else out there had experience with something similar.

Comment: @HABO I don't really care who is making the modifications.  I just need my application to be able to discern when someone else has made a change.

Comment: @sparks, given that the reason is to detect changes, put a trigger on the table to log changes somewhere and check the log

Comment: @DanBracuk If someone has full access to the DB they can disable the trigger and/or tamper with the log itself.

Answer (score 1):

all i can think of here, would be some sort of MAC or signature schema

derive a hash from the data in the columns you want to protect, plus a secret value to obtain a message authentication code, and store that in another column ...

your application can calculate that MAC again when you want to test for integrity ...

problem: that secret needs to be stored somewhere ...

you can also setup this as a digital signature schema where you application only holds the verification key, and a service somewhere will timestamp hash and sign the data for your application ... that way, you only have to keep the secret key of that service a real secret ...

Comment: We thought of the hashing solution, but the problem there is that the user can tamper with this like in the scenario described in my example. i.e. (1) values A, B, C, and hash(A, B, C) are store in DB (2) user uses the application to change a value, now we have values A, B, D, and hash(A, B, D) in the DB (3) User directly modifies the database to replace D with C and hash(A, B, D) with hash(A, B, C) which he obtained from step 1.

Comment: to prevent this, you need at least one database without public access to store the timestamp or one nonce per record in the original database...